# ERROR: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a record using mongoose.js framework method **model.Create** as below example, i am geting an error as **Cannot read property '_id' of undefined**

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });

    var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

    var Aryobj = [{ size: 'small' }, {size:'large'}];

    Tank.create(Aryobj, function (err, small, large) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
       console.log("small ID:"+small._id);
       console.log("large ID:"+large._id);

    })
```

ther is any problem my code? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is just a typo in your code if you change the line (replace yourSchema with schema)

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);
```

to

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

As the definition is for the var schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
```

I ran the script with the typo corrected and it outputted two IDs.